# Will MKMapView automatically use Google Maps in iOS6, as google maps is restored in iOS6?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

As apple has restored google maps in iOS6, if I'm using `MKMapView` in my iPhone app, will it automatically use google maps?

Comment: Apple did not restore Google maps in iOs6, they have actually removed them from iOs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Google Maps in your app, you should use Google Maps SDK for iOS

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios

Comment: can you please let me know how to use this SDK in my app? do we need to use mapkit framework?

Comment: @Dpk - Read the docs in the link supplied by Alexey. It's all very new. API keys are not being handed out by Google yet so you can't use it straight away.  Also it is only compatible with ios6+. If you need backwards compatibility (and draw on the experience of loads of other developers) you should stick with mapKit.

Comment: Also be aware that the Google SDK has really low limits regarding the number of searches per day your application can perform (if it uses that part of the API).

Comment: @HeWas: The new SDK supports iOS 5.1 or later.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's an Apple API so will use Apple's default maps.

Apple has not restored Google Maps. Google has released an iPhone app.

Comment: The link says exactly what He said.  Google released an iOS version of Google Maps.  Apple had nothing to do with that except for approving it.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner so my question is, if i use mapkit framework in my app, it will use apple's map, is it so? Please reply

Comment: @Dpk Yes, as per my answer. If you _need_ google maps, you will have to use google's api as per Alexey's answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the source of the confusion (at least for me), is the following text snippet from [Apple's MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html):

> Important: In iOS 5.1 and earlier, the Map Kit framework uses the
>   Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data. Use of specific
>   classes of this framework (and their associated interfaces) is subject
>   to the Google Mobile Maps terms of service. You can find these terms
>   of service at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html.

So while I agree with `"If you want to use Google Maps in your app, you should use Google Maps SDK for iOS"`, by reading Apple's documentation, it seems that MKMapView is somehow bound to GMM.