# MapKit and MapView select to implement for map based application

Tags: iphone, google-maps, integration

i am new to ios developemt, i have one confusion please clear it, in iOS6 if i use MKMapView its show google or apple map and in apple documentation there is a term called Map App , according to me its inbuilt app which we can use it directly pleas tell me . Am i talking right .

thank you in advance please please .

Comment: I think it shows apple map...

Comment: See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619431/mkmapview-shows-googlemap-in-ios-5-and-apple-map-in-ios-6 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965437/will-mkmapview-automatically-use-google-maps-in-ios6-as-google-maps-is-restored

Comment: than you vishal, is it possible to only show navigation part in MapApp   and hide all other part ,please please help .

Comment: Yeah it is possible that you show navigation part...check on github you can find no. of example to do this...